# Did 007 exist before James Bond?

Tags: james-bond

*<sup>This question is inspired by the [recent news](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/lashana-lynch-007-james-bond_n_5d2c59b1e4b02a5a5d5df896) of Lashana Lynch taking over as 007.</sup>*

---

Did the 007 position within MI6 begin with James Bond or did he take it over from a previous agent?

Comment: Although not in the original Fleming novels, it does appear that other 00 agents have been replaced see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/00_Agent So in the universe of James Bond, it certainly seems possible that another agent could be 007 either before or after Bond.

Comment: If you want to delve into the real world, 16th-century royal advisor John Dee was known to sign sensitive documents to Queen Elizabeth with '007', meaning for her eyes only. The 00 looked like eyes, with the number 7 generally considered good luck.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### That depends on the source

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/00_Agent), Bond is the only 007 in Ian Fleming's Bond stories:

> James Bond is the only agent 007. In the novel You Only Live Twice, Bond was transferred into another branch and given the number 7777, suggesting there was no active agent 007 in that time; he is later reinstated as 007 in the novel The Man with the Golden Gun.

But the Bond stories from Anthony Horowitz's novel, he takes it from another agent:

> In Anthony Horowitz's continuation novel, set before the events of Casino Royale, an unnamed agent 007 is murdered, which leads to James Bond taking over the code-number in Forever and A Day, thus marking his first ever assignment as a 00-agent.

It's never explicitly said in the movies, but the first Eon Production Films 007 movie was [Dr. No (1962)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._No_(film)) which is an adaptation of Ian Fleming's novel, so we can safely assume that the movies have the same backstory as the novels.

Comment: There is no proof of it of course, but there is also the fan theory that each actor is actually a _different_ Bond, the prior one having retired from the field or er... been retired _in_ the field, just not on camera for us to watch.

Comment: @Baldrickk If for no other reason than the fact that Bond in 2018 is somehow younger than he was in 1962?

Comment: Actual numbering is 007a, 007b..

Comment: @Baldrickk That theory doesn't really hold water. Many times throughout the series we get references that point to the fact that it is the same person.

Comment: Actually - there's a clear indication that every bond from lazenby to dalton are the same bond- Moore gets his revenge on a wheelchair bound, and uncredited Blofeld in for your eyes only, for the death of Tracy Bond in On Her Majesty's Secret Service, and [Tracy Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy_Bond) is referenced in Licence to Kill and Spy who loved me

Comment: Is the wiki entry really evidence that there was never a 007 before James, though? All this really says is that the novels don't contain another agent 007, not that there was never one before. I'm not sure that that part really answers the question at all.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Do we, or do we get clear indications from MI6 that there is only the one and only James Bond? Look, he took revenge on the killer of his wife here! That other agent you killed and had a head stuck on a pike was some other guy, the genuine legendary super agent James Bond is still alive. Trust us, we're MI6…

Comment: @JourneymanGeek But Lazenby at least is not the same as Connery - he even says in his first fight scene after getting the snot beat out of him that "This never happened to the other guy".

Comment: Well, that could be breaking the 4th wall - and there's a reason I left out Connery there.

Comment: @Baldrickk - that theory would suggest that 007 isn't the code name at all, but _007 James Bond_ is the code name.

Comment: Isn't it established that the Craig films are a reboot, not set in the same continuity as the older ones?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not only do we see Tracy Bond's grave, we also see his father Andrew Bond's grave in *SkyFall*. I think the Bond-as-codename theory has been debunked many times now, and been around so long that the scene in *Skyfall* was there to explicitly renounce it..

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional plus Kincade, the groundskeeper in Skyfall, specifically knew Bond as a child growing up at the Skyfall estate.

Comment: Maybe each Bond is the previous Bond's son? That way the references and revenge make sense, as does the reference to Tracy Bond? :D

Comment: I don't really understand why this answer has so many upvotes. Wikipedia is not a first party source.

Comment: The DC Films are a reboot, so it can be a whole new ball game as per any theories. @JustinLardinois  They can do whatever they want with it, pretty much.

Comment: @MattBurland I'd go so far as to say that 007 is a designation and James bond would be the code name ;)

Answer (score 7):

The spy designation 007 dates back to well before the time of Ian Fleming.

Queen Elizabeth I used spies, as did most people in power in those days, and one of these was a colourful character called John Dee who had the code name 007:  *vide* http://www.woe.edu.pl/content/dr-john-dee-original-007

It is thought that Ian Fleming chose 007 for his spy from reading about John Dee.

Answer (score 5):

Alec Trevelyan played agent 006 in Goldeneye, which clearly implies the numbers are sequential and incremental.

So its reasonable to assume that there are have been least 6 other double-0 agents and potentially more afterward.

Horowitz's book (*Trigger Mortis*) is not a Fleming book, but it "draws inspiration from unpublished notes" and therefore has less "authority" or credulence than Fleming's own words. However there are only 12 Fleming novels and 9 short stories published in the Canon from which to draw.    (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_James_Bond_novels_and_short_stories )

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP was not asking about 001-006. OP was asking about 007a, 007b, etc.

Comment: The existence of 006 doesn't seem to imply that the numbers are sequential and incremental. Maybe each agent gets to choose their own number, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It *implies* it but doesn't *prove* it.

Comment: @Segfault It doesn't imply it at all. "A implies B" means that, if A happens, then B must happen also. It is not true that, if there is a 006, the numbers must be sequential and incremental. The existence of 006 is consistent with the hypothesis that the numbers are sequential and incremental but you can't say anything stronger than that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby we're using different definitions of imply. My usage (and Criggies) is the one that is synonymous with "hint".

Comment: it's funny people are stuck on the word implies, the fact that there was a 006 to me this is a clear indication of sequential numbering

Comment: @Huangism Goldeneye also shows Alex's character as somewhat of a father-elder type figure to James, with a more world-aware attitude and a "you'll understand someday"   This again implies that 006 has been in the game longer than 007.

Comment: @Huangism Id have to go back and reread the novels and watch the movies again, but its fairly well established that the “00” designation is the “license to kill”, not that agents are sequentially numbered as they come and go. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/00_Agent

Comment: When I saw _GE_ in the theater (as a teen), the conclusion I immediately reached re: 006 was that their having adjacent numbers was a coincidence meant by filmmakers to bolster the idea that James and Alec are unusually friendly colleagues -- really solid buddies, not merely fellow agents. **It is absurd that agents' codenumbers would be assigned sequentially,** because to do so would reveal to Britain's enemies how many agents HMSS employs! E.g. the Soviets would, like other commenters here, deduce that Britain has at least 7 top-tier spies. No spymaster would make such a careless blunder.

Comment: There are at least 9 double-0 agents if we accept that they are sequential - 009 is killed at the start of Octopussy.